# install cyrllic fonts in matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, fonts

I am unable to display cyrillic or arabic characters in matplot lib figures.[image]

As you can see the square blocks appear under x axis. I am working on ipython3 notebook.

Comment: You should write your code in text properly format it, not just paste an image of your code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to write a minimal, complete, verifiable question. Good questions tend to get better answers and be answered quicker.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify Matplotlib to use a font which support your intended language. But you have to make sure that your system contains the font which can show your intended language. First you need to find the language code your intended language, find it [here](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php). Then, if you are on Linux system, you can use the following command to find a font which support your language:

```
fc-list :lang=<LANGUAGE_CODE>
```

Take Chinese for example, the language code is `zh`, so to find a language which support Chinese, you can use

```
fc-list :lang=zh
```

[image]

Maybe there are several fonts which support your language. The font name is listed after the font directory. Just pick one.

After you have picked up a font. Add the following code to the front your source code,

```
import matplotlib as mpl
# <FONT_NAME> is the font picked by you, don't forget to 
# enclose it with quotation marks
mpl.rcParams['font.family']='<FONT_NAME>'
```

Then you should be able to see the characters appear.

Comment: I tried to put this as `mpl.rcParams['font.family']=FreeSerif`. 
But the error I get is this, `NameError: name 'FreeSerif' is not defined
`
I am sure what it the problem.

Comment: Of course, you should enclose the name with `''`. The font name should be a string. If you do not enclose it with `''`, it will be treated as a variable.

Comment: Just use `mpl.rcParams['font.family']='FreeSerif'`.